# Spring MVC cannot found the URI mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

This is the web.xml, it should be correct because it is generated by Intellij.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is the controller

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(ModelMap model) {

        System.out.print("index");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

when I create new project in Intellij, I checked these options.

```
Java EE > Web Application
    > Spring MVC
    > Hibernate
```

I cannot access the page correctly

if I use "localhost:8080/test"

I can see the page, but the controller is not executed, because this URL will access "localhost:8080/test/index.jsp"

if I use "localhost:8080/test/index", result is 404

if I use "localhost:8080/test/index", result is 404, and server log will show this error

```
    WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/index.form] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

I changed "*.form" to "/*", but I still got same error.

What is still missing in my project?

---

Update, these are applicationContext.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml, these files are also generated by Intellij

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

Comment: did you try to put method type at method level, i.e. GET/POST?

Comment: Please can you also post the dispatcher spring config? And the version of spring used?

Comment: @Neeraj   I tried `method = RequestMethod.GET`, but it is not work.

Comment: @KevinBayes I added applicationContext.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml, these files are generated by Intellij, and the Spring version is "Spring MVC-4.1.1.RELEASE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IndexController` is not being found by Spring.
You added a @Controller but you didn't tell Spring load them.
Change your dispatcher-servlet.xml and add this.
The important part here is the `context:component-scan` which tells Spring to look for annotated classes inside the package.

Here is the reference.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="<your controller package here>" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```